# python - binary search stuck in infinite loop

Tags: python, binary-search

Could I please have advise on my binary search code? It is stuck in an infinite loop. I have gone through a code a couple of times but don't seem to be able to spot the problem. I have omitted the first part of the code as it works well. In short, the first part of the code reads a set of data into a dictionary list called 'bait_dict'.

```
import csv

def comparison (input_file, output_file):
    count = 0
    count_in = 0
    count_out = 0
    for line in input_file:
        count += 1
        chrom_file = line[0]
        base_file = int(line[1])
        if chrom_file in bait_dict:
            for value in bait_dict[chrom_file]:
                low = 0
                high = len (bait_dict[chrom_file]) - 1
            while low <= high:
                mid = (low + high)//2
                start, end = bait_dict[chrom_file][mid]
                if base_file < start:
                    high = mid - 1
                elif base_file > end:
                    low = mid + 1
                elif start <= base_file and base_file <= end:
                    count_in += 1  
                    output_file.writerow(line)
                    break
            count_out += 1
```

Comment: have you tried sprinkling print statements to see exactly where it's getting stuck?

Comment: I've a feeling if you add "else: assert False" to your if...elif tree, the program'll crash due to a failed assertion.

Comment: you can insert `print base_file,bait_dict[chrom_file]` after this line `if chrom_file in bait_dict`. The last line printed out is the input that caused your program stuck. Then paste the input here.  Besides, I don't get why you need this iteration `for value in bait_dict[chrom_file]`

Comment: thanks for all your helpful comments. The for loop was causing the problem. It was causing the while loop to reiterate over the same line. Thanks very much again. Much appreciated.